# Blogger/Blogspot - How to fix Http to Https redirect SEO violation

Tags: blogger, blogspot

In SEO analysis report of my blog, I found this violation message more than thousand times.

```
The link to "http://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/ASP.Net" has resulted in HTTP redirection to "https://myblog.blogspot.com/search/label/ASP.Net".
Search engines can only pass page rankings and other relevant data through a single redirection hop. Using unnecessary redirects can have a negative impact on page ranking.
```

I searched on net and I am feeling like to set either custom robot.txt file to disable crawling of http pages or may be I have to set 301 permanent redirect. Either way can anybody suggest how to do this in blogger/blogspot.

I checked this question ([Use 301 Redirect In Google Blogger/Blogspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795465/use-301-redirect-in-google-blogger-blogspot)) seems similar to this, but the solution is quite time consuming as it needs to be fixed for every post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option present within Blogger settings (Under Settings  Basic  HTTPS  HTTPS redirect)  which will allow you to set up 301 Redirects on a sitewide basis.

[image]

If you want to prevent the round trip from HTTP to HTTPS without updating the post content for your users (won't work for crawlers), you will need to add the following meta tag in the `<head>` portion of the template code.

```
<meta content='upgrade-insecure-requests' http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' />
```

In case of a custom domain, you can also set up CloudFlare and use their *Always Use HTTPS* and *Automatic HTTPS Rewrites* features to setup 301 redirects.

Comment: Thanks @PrayagVerma, I did this. Still SEO analysis report showing me same message. It is successfully redirecting Http traffic to Https, but SEO message not affected. How to remove this violation.

Comment: Could you share the blog URL on which you are facing this issue? Also the tool that you are using for testing is SEOProfiler or a different one?

Comment: My blog is- http://idreesdotnet.blogspot.com/ .......and using this tool in IIS. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/search-engine-optimization-toolkit

Comment: @PrayafVerma, Is there anything missing with the blog or the tool ?

Comment: No there is nothing missing from your side. The issue is that I haven't used the tool that you mentioned and hence I can't help much with the specific errors. But I tried checking the blog via different tools (like https://httpstatus.io/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fidreesdotnet.blogspot.com) and confirmed that the 301 redirect are set up across the website and it is no longer a temporary redirection