# I want to redirect only the beginning of the blog link to another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, blogger

I want to redirect from
https://example1.blogspot.com/2018/5/ttttttttt
to me
https://example2.blogspot.com/2018/5/ttttttttt
In all blog posts
In other words, I want to just convert the blog link and leave the rest of the post link

I found this code online and tried to modify it to do what I wanted but failed because it continues to convert the link to the homepage of example2

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var d='<data:blog.url/>';
  d=d.replace(/.*\/\/[^\/]*/, '');
  location.href = 'https://example2.blogspot.com';
</script>
```

Comment: Doing this server side would be a much better idea, especially for SEO. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795465/use-301-redirect-in-google-blogger-blogspot

Comment: Woooow thanks alot